# Differentiate between mobile and desktop

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a component that should change the layout depends on device.

On mobile it should stack the content, for example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ktoee?file=/demo.tsx

On desktop the content should be placed like:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ykyng?file=/demo.tsx

How can I solve with flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This achieves the same effect without media queries. The flexbox container is set to wrap to multiple rows with

flex-wrap: wrap;

The text is set to expand to available space using

flex-grow: 1;

and to have minimum width of 400px with

flex-basis: 400px;

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-f2pc8

Comment: On mobile, the text **Live From Space** should be above the picture.

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: lets use flex-wrap: wrap-reverse then

Comment: How about now? Does it look better?

Comment: Almost, on mobile the picture should be in between the title and the text, for example https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#complex-interaction

Comment: I see, that might take some more time, i'll get back to this later if no-one has answered